# MSBuild task fails silently after using TFS API in a custom task

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Hi I'm using TFS2010 to build a (master) project which itself sequentially calls two MSBuild tasks to build other (child) projects. The first child project uses a custom task which utilizes TFS API (to read information about build configurations). If the first child project executes this custom task (this task always executes successfully), the second call to MSBuild task (in a master project) always fails silently. In the log file I just get the following:

```
Task "MSBuild"
  Global Properties:
    <Some custom properties here>

Build FAILED.
  0 Warning(s)
  0 Error(s)
```

If that custom task is not executed everything builds fine. Both projects use other custom tasks (MSBuild.ExtensionPack and a couple of those written by me) and none of them makes the build fail.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the issue and to find out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can attach to `msbuild` process and try to debug. I do so in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that applying `[LoadInSeparateAppDomain]` attribute to the task class (I also applied `[Serializable]` and derived the task class from `AppDomainIsolatedTask`) solves the issue. Still I wonder how to troubleshoot such stuff.